# Obtaining a Ruby on Rails variable from a String?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, variables

I would like to ask if it is possible to create a new ROR variable from a string.
For example, I would like to have something like below:

```
member = Member.find_by_id 1
user = "member"
```

I want `#{user}` to return me the actual member variable
and also `#{user}.name` to return me the same result as `member.name`

Comment: `member = Member.find_by_id 1` this I got it. What do you mean by `user = "member"`

Comment: I would like to find a way to convert the string "member" into the variable member that I have previously defined. I was assigning the variable user the value "member" just for the purpose of the example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help

```
instance_variable_set("@#{member}", user)
```

if not then please spent some time on  instance_variable_set, it will solve your problem